# read() reads characters that do not exist in the file

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

The system call `read()` takes characters from a file and it also reads characters that don't exist at the end of each buffer.

The file has string:
"AAOOOOOBRRRRRRIIIIIGGGGGGIIIIIINNNNNAAAALLLLLEEEEXXZZZSS"

When it reads, the buffer contains:
"AAOOOOOBRRRRRRIIIIIGGGGGGIIIIIINNNNNAAAALLLLLEEEEXXZZZSS??Bf?"

As you see, the last four characters don't exist in the file

My code:

```
void trOpcionS(int src, int dst, char *cadena)
{
    //BUFFER DE LECTURA
    char buff[100];

    //BUFFER DE ESCRITURA TRAS ANALIZAR EL DE LECTURA
    char buffRes[100];

    //bytes leidos
    ssize_t r = 0;

    //bucle de lectura
    while ((r = read(src, buff, 100)) > 0)
    {
        char *ptrBuf = buff;
        char *ptrBufRes = buffRes;
        //bucle para analizar la lectura
        while (*ptrBuf != '\0')
        { 
            //BUCLE QUE RECORRE EL BUFFER
            int pos = 0;
            while (*(cadena + pos) != '\0')
            { 
                //BUCLE QUE RECORRE LA CADENA A TRANSFORMAR
                if (*(cadena + pos) == *ptrBuf)
                { 
                    //SI ENCUENTRO UNA EQUIVALENCIA, SE ESCRIBE Y SE SALTAN TODAS SUS REPETICIONES
                    *ptrBufRes = *ptrBuf;
                    while (*(ptrBuf + 1) == *ptrBufRes)
                    {
                        ptrBuf++;
                    }
                    ptrBufRes++;
                    break;
                }
                pos++;
            }
            //SI EL VALOR NO SE ENCUENTRA EN LA CADENA SE ESCRIBE SIN MÁS
            if (pos == strlen(cadena))
            {
                *ptrBufRes = *ptrBuf;
                ptrBufRes++;
            }
            ptrBuf++;
        }
        *ptrBufRes = '\0';

        printf("Reading: %s\n", buff);
        printf("%s\n", buffRes);
        ssize_t w = write(dst, buffRes, strlen(buffRes));
    }
}
```

Comment: `read` returns a value. Use it.

Comment: Please, post your code. Probably, you didn't initialize the buffer before filling it, v.gr. with null chars. If you don't want to do that, you will have at least to append a `'\0'` char at the end of the string you read for the case you want to print the content of the buffer itself. In that case, the size of your buffer will need space for an extra char. Take this into account when declaring the buffer.

Comment: Yes, my fault, I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while((r = read(src, buff, 100)) > 0){
    char* ptrBuf = buff;
    char* ptrBufRes = buffRes;
    //bucle para analizar la lectura
    while(*ptrBuf != '\0'){ //BUCLE QUE RECORRE EL BUFFER
```

after you read the buffer you missed to add the final null character the second *while* expect, so that one continues up to find a null character you never set, of course this is an undefined behavior.

You can add the null character at *buff[r]* but that supposes you read up to 99 bytes rather than 100 or *buff* needs to be sized 101, else just replace the second *while* by

```
while (ptrBuf != (buff + 100)) {
```

Warning there is also a problem in the loop

> ```
> while(*(ptrBuf + 1) == *ptrBufRes)
> ```

where you can go out of the read bytes / out of *buff*

Comment: I have tried, but I use the same way of using in others own methods with the same text file and it does not happen.

Comment: @ÁlvaroAfonsoLópez the first version of my answer was before you added you code, I edited my answer after I see you added it

Comment: @ÁlvaroAfonsoLópez, no, *read* reads a block of bytes, not necessary a string, so there is no reason it adds a final null char, and the read block contains null character(s) if there are present in the part of the file you read in

Comment: the function: `read()` does not NUL terminate the read characters.  so checking for `NUL` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

this statement sequence:

```
while ((r = read(src, buff, 100)) > 0)
{
```

needs to be followed by:

```
    buf[ r ] = '\0';
```

so as to NUL terminate the read string because the function: `read()` does not do that.